# mySQL CodeIgniter - Syntax Error Number: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to wrap my head around this and I can't seem to figure out how this query returns a syntax error. My knowlegde of mySQL is small as I'm just getting to grips with it.

This is the query I'm trying to execute:

```
function _delete_leaf_node($id){

$query ="";

$query .=" SELECT @myLeft := lft, @myRight := rgt, @myWidth := rgt - lft + 1";
$query .=" FROM pages";
$query .=" WHERE id =".$id.";";

$query .=" DELETE FROM pages WHERE lft BETWEEN @myLeft AND @myRight;";
$query .=" UPDATE pages SET rgt = rgt - @myWidth WHERE rgt > @myRight;";
$query .=" UPDATE pages SET lft = lft - @myWidth WHERE lft > @myRight;";    

$this->_custom_query($query);
```

}

This is the error I get returned:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM pages WHERE lft = @myLeft UPDATE pages SET rgt = rgt + 1, lft = lft ' at line 1

I have checked if the right id is passed. Perhaps the variables are not set in the proper manner? I just don't know how one would check for that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can not run two queries in single call.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Suresh! I didn't know that. I will try to split them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function _delete_leaf_node($id){

    $query  =" SELECT @myLeft := lft, @myRight := rgt, @myWidth := rgt - lft + 1";
    $query .=" FROM pages";
    $query .=" WHERE id =".intval($id);

    $this->_custom_query($query);

    $this->_custom_query("DELETE FROM pages WHERE lft BETWEEN @myLeft AND @myRight");
    $this->_custom_query("UPDATE pages SET rgt = rgt - @myWidth WHERE rgt > @myRight");
    $this->_custom_query("UPDATE pages SET lft = lft - @myWidth WHERE lft > @myRight");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Your Common Sense! That did the trick! One question, why did you use .intval($id) instead of just $id?

Comment: because every SQL literal ought to be formatted according to it's role at the time of query building. No exceptions.

Comment: excellent! I'll keep that in mind from now on.

Comment: Also keep in mind that there are at leas 5 different kinds of literals, each requires it's own distinct formatting, inapplicable to others.